# Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration

Tags: java, hibernate

I have been trying to fix this and I can't seem to make it work

**Err Log**

```
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.hib.work.HiberUtil.<clinit>(HiberUtil.java:18)
        at com.hib.work.Test.update(Test.java:70)
        at com.hib.work.Test.main(Test.java:21)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1487)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1428)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1414)
        at com.hib.work.HiberUtil.<clinit>(HiberUtil.java:13)
        ... 2 more
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 

    63; L'attribut "ressource" doit être déclaré pour le type d'élément "mapping".
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.addDTDDefaultAttrsAndValidate(XMLDTDValidator.java:1253)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1917)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:763)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:353)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2717)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
        at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1484)
        ... 5 more
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/bd_inscription</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">public</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <mapping ressource="./comms/hib/work/CLASS_NAME.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: I have an error i can't fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have a typo:

```
<mapping ressource="./comms/hib/work/CLASS_NAME.hbm.xml" />
```

change it with one 's' like this:

```
<mapping resource="./comms/hib/work/CLASS_NAME.hbm.xml" />
```

In english, it's resource ;)